# Converting dictionary with tuple as key and values as array to a pandas dataframe

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

I have the following dictionary:

dict = {(0, 6): array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 1 ,1]]),
(0, 9): array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1]])}

I would like to convert it to a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| Key | v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 | v5 | v6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (0,6) | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| (0,9) | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I do not want the key to be the index.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
d =  {(0, 6): np.array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 1 ,1]]), 
      (0, 9): np.array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1]])}


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: v[0] for k, v in d.items()}, orient='index')
df = df.rename_axis('Key').rename(columns=lambda x: f'v{x+1}').reset_index()
print (df)
      Key  v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6
0  (0, 6)   1   2   3   0   1   1
1  (0, 9)   1   2   3   0   1   1
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(list(d.values()))).rename(columns=lambda x: f'v{x+1}')
df.insert(0,'Key',list(d.keys()))
print (df)
      Key  v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6
0  (0, 6)   1   2   3   0   1   1
1  (0, 9)   1   2   3   0   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael this answered my query